# Python Binary Number Class: Numpy Array Manipulation Getting "TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, typeerror

I am trying to create a class called "Binary" and the main idea of it is to take a string representing a fixed width binary number that is 16 bits as it's only parameter and store it as a numpy integer array into it's one instance variable "bit_array".

If the given string is greater than 16 characters or contains anything other than 0's and 1's, it is to raise a RuntimeError. If "string" is less than 16 characters, it is to pad on the leftmost digit of given string onto the start of the numpy array until the resulting array contains exactly 16 digits. The given string defaults to '0' and accepts an empty string, treating an empty string as '0'. The code I have written for init is as follows (in "**hw4.py**" - the main file for this assignment):

```
import numpy as np

class Binary:

    def __init__(self, string='0'):
        if not string:
            string = '0'
        else:
            if len(string) > 16:
                raise RuntimeError
            else:
                for i in string:
                    if i != '1' and i != '0':
                        raise RuntimeError

        if len(string) == 16:
            int_arr = np.array(tuple(string))
            self.bit_array = int_arr
        else:
            int_arr_inc = np.array(tuple(string))
            if int_arr_inc[0] == 0:
                pad = np.zeros((16 - len(int_arr_inc)), int)
            else:
                pad = np.ones((16 - len(int_arr_inc)), int)
            self.bit_array = np.concatenate((pad, int_arr_inc))
```

There is also an eq overloaded method intended to compare the bit_array of another "Binary" object in this class (this passes the spec's test case so there shouldn't be any changes required here, just more for being transparent):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if str(self.bit_array) == str(other.bit_array):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**The spec requires that there is no use of list() or any form of lists at all in the init method.** The method is not to return anything and it's only purpose is to build a Binary object that has a bit_array that converts the string parameter into a numpy integer array. The test cases I have to test against calls the following test case (in a test file "**hw4_test.py**"):

```
from hw4 import Binary
import unittest, numpy as np

class TestBinary(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.bin_0 = Binary("")
        self.bin_1 = Binary("01")
        self.bin_2 = Binary("010")

    def test_init(self):
        self.assertTrue(all(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == self.bin_0.bit_array))
        self.assertTrue(all(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]) == self.bin_1.bit_array))
        self.assertTrue(all(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]) == self.bin_2.bit_array))
```

However, the first test case here fails, giving me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17606\Desktop\ISTA-350\hw4\hw4_test.py", line 30, in test_init
    self.assertTrue(all(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == self.bin_0.bit_array))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I've tried many ways of creating the numpy arrays, such as fromstring (which is deprecated anyways) and trying with a map of the parameter string, to no avail. As the test case code above shows, I am expecting

```
Binary("")
```

To result in a Binary object containing a bit_array of a numpy array like

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But the TypeError above keeps occuring. Any ideas? I am having trouble understanding where I am even iterating over anything that could be a bool type. I am using Python 3.10 on Windows 10 with PyCharm as my IDE.

P.S
This is for a school course and I am not very concerned about conventions or efficiency for this. Just syntax and logic :)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but `Binary("")` is setting `bit_array = ['1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '0']` instead of all zeroes.

Comment: Notice that the elements of `bit_array` are strings, not numbers, I think that will help you figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: In `np.array(tuple(string))`: `tuple(string)` is a tuple whose elements are the characters in `string`. Use `np.array(int(c) for c in string)` to create an array of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar THIS! My headache is finally subsiding. I can't believe I overlooked the type of what was going into the array. The TypeError pointing me at iterating over a bool somewhere threw me way off from thinking it could be this. Thank you so much! (fyi - it  actually does still need the tuple() around the comprehension code :) )

Comment: If anyone has this issue, @Barmar 's third comment using the int-ified iteration over the string is the solution! (with tuple() around it, however)

Comment: Feel free to write a full answer.